# How to stop on hover changes of swing components?

Tags: java, swing, awt

I am using a semi-transparent JPanel inside which I have some Swing components such as combo boxes and radio buttons. That looks great, but when I hover the mouse on comboboxes and radio buttons everything gets messed up. The border of those components and the text background of radio buttons get weird colours even after I set the opaque false.

I know when you hover the mouse some changes happen to those components but it doesn't looks nice in my case. I don't want it to happen. So how to stop it? I mean it should look as same as when it was not on hover.

Comment: Consider providing a runnable example, it sounds like your not changing the opaque property of the panel but have, instead, used a alpha based color

Comment: Yes I am using an alpha based color, But if i set the opaque of the panel to false, then i can't get the semi transparency

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swing only knows how to paint transparent or opaque components, it has no idea how to paint anything in between.

To do this,my need set the panel transparent (opaque `false`) and override its `paintComponent` method and paint the transparency fill yourself...

```
public class TranslucentPanel extends JPanel {
    public TranslucentPanel() {
        setOpaque(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.SrcOver.derive(0.5f));
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        g2d.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: is there a way to stop on hover effects?

Comment: @user3641302 That's not what you want to do, you've messed with how painting works, so you need to fix that problem, not try and band aid it with for hacks...

Comment: This code gives an error. g2d.fill(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight()); required Shape, found int int int int. I really don't understand how painting works. I just started my first semester in college, so please help me to get rid of this problem

Comment: Sorry should be fillRect

Comment: Actually i can't get it work. I am using a panel with setBackground(new Color(66,27,0,100)). Swing components are opaque false. I just drag and drop swing components from the palette. Now what should i do to overcome the problem?

Comment: Create a custom component as shown above, this will act as the base component.  You would simply set it's background to the full opaque color and adjust the alpha level within the `paintComponent` method